# Custom Java Code Library Usage Tips

Tags: java, javadoc

I am developing a library which is used for some specific validation operations.  Every thing is ok for me in usage, *but when I publish it, every time developers need to read manual document.*

So, I want to show usage tips like shown blow.

[image]

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write JavaDoc comments in your code and then you can generate JavaDoc html.

JavaDoc comments are special comments which are between `/**` and `*/` and can be used to generate JavaDoc. e.g.

```
/**
 * Class description.
 * <p>
 * Some more details
 * 
 * @author Edd
 */
public class MyClass {

    /**
     * Method description.
     * 
     * @param param
     *            important parameter
     */
    public static void myMethod(String param) {

    }
}
```

This would then look like this as a tooltip:

[image: JavaDoc tooltip]

When you release your library for other developers to use, you would typically release it as a jar file. When you package up your jar you should also generate a javadoc.jar file to accompany your jar. This can then be used by other developers to get the usage tips.

Comment: Yes, but unless the JavaDoc is packages with the library, it will not be visible to a programmer using the library.

Comment: @Tichodroma I've added a brief note on generating javadoc.jar files in response to your comment

Answer (score 1):

Write JavaDoc comments and publish them together with your library.

If you are using Maven, you can use the [`javadoc:jar` goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/jar-mojo.html) of the [Maven Javadoc Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/).

Answer (score 1):

Read about and use javadoc, here:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html